# How to animate one big image to only show a part of itself inside screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one big image.

```
width = 500 px;
height = 2000 px;
```

[image]

I want to show that image inside viewport of a widget. In this case the widget is going to be background and it is going to take the full width and height of the screen.

[image]

I have couple of breakpoints on that image that need to align with bottom of the screen.
[ 1000px, 1500 px, 2000 px ]

[image]
[image]
[image]

What needs to be shown is everything from that bottom line until it fills the screen to the top, while the width is being stretched to fit the screen.

I also want to animate the changes from one background to another.

How would I approach this solution?

I tried to use alignment from `Image.asset` but I cannot map precisely the alignment to needed breakpoints.

```
    return TweenAnimationBuilder(
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      tween: Tween<double>(
          begin: alignmentForScreen(previousScreen),
          end: alignmentForScreen(currentScreen)),
      builder: (context, value, _) => Image.asset(
        "assets/imgs/bg/home_bg.jpeg",
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        alignment: Alignment(0,value),
      ),
    );
```

Here is the image that I want to use:

[image]

It is `553*2048` and breakpoints are drawn as a line at the height of

```
 1365
 1712
 2032
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to do with a `ListView` nested inside a `SizedBox`

```
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,  //Constraints of viewport to fit screen
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,  //Constraints of viewport to fit screen
  child: ListView(  //Scrollable widget
    shrinkWrap: true, //Reduce ListView's height to the childrens's
    controller: listViewController,  //Allows to programatically animate between offsets of the ListView (1365, 1712, 2032)
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),  //The user can't swipe the picture up or down
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: [
      Image.asset("assets/svg/ZFh5j.jpg", fit: BoxFit.fitHeight) //BigImage
    ],
  ),
),
```

To animate between offsets in the `ListView` add a `ScrollController`:

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  Screen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  ScrollController listViewController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,  //Constraints of viewport to fit screen
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,  //Constraints of viewport to fit screen
            child: ListView(  //Scrollable widget
              shrinkWrap: true, //Reduce ListView's height to the childrens's
              controller: listViewController,  //Allows to programatically animate between offsets of the ListView (1365, 1712, 2032)
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),  //The user can't swipe the picture up or down
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: [
                Image.asset("assets/svg/ZFh5j.jpg") //BigImage
              ],
            ),
          ),
          //contents on top of the background here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can animate the `ListView`'s position like this:

(You can put this function in a `GestureDetector`. The `ListView` must already be built before animating it)

```
listViewController.animateTo(/*offset*/, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeInOutQuad);
```

This will scroll the `ListView` to "offset" pixels from the top, so animating to the offset `2032` won't align the lower line of the image with the bottom constraint of the viewport. To make it easy, add a `SizedBox` in the `ListView` before the image

```
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,  //Constraints of viewport to fit screen
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,  //Constraints of viewport to fit screen
  child: ListView(  //Scrollable widget
    shrinkWrap: true, //Reduce ListView's height to the childrens's
    controller: listViewController,  //Allows to programatically animate between offsets of the ListView (1365, 1712, 2032)
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),  //The user can't swipe the picture up or down
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height), //Must be height of viewport in order to work
      SizedBox(
        height: 2048,
        width: 553,
        child: Image.asset("assets/svg/ZFh5j.jpg", fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,) //BigImage
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Now calling `listViewController.animateTo(2032, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeInOutQuad)` should align the lower line with the bottom of the viewport

Comment: you da man. wrapping the image in sized box to match the image height with real resolution is genial.

Comment: I can award bounty in 5 hours

Comment: thx to your comment, I did simple solution and it works. 

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      reverse: true,
      controller: scrollController,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 2048,
        width: 553,
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/imgs/bg/home_bg.jpeg",
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I want to award the bounty to you, so if you can update the answer :D

Comment: Glad you found the answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer above, the solution I used was to wrap the image in sized box of the same size like image in pixels. When you put that in `SingleChildScrollView` with `reversed = true`, animating scroll to offset will be pixel precise.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      reverse: true,
      controller: scrollController,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 2048,
        width: 553,
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/imgs/bg/home_bg.jpeg",
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

```
      bgOffsets = [100, 336.0, 411.0, 1200.0];
      scrollController.animateTo(bgOffsets[currentScreen.index],
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.bounceOut);
```

Comment: Nice solution ;)